# How to filter user input that edits the html/css of a website (like in Tumblr)?

Tags: security, filter, xss, sql-injection, backend

Tumblr allows users to edit the HTML and CSS of their blogs through a Templating system. In fact, it even allows users to include their own external scripts into their pages. Doing this obviously opens a lot of security holes for Tumblr; however, it's obviously doing fine. What's even more interesting is how Tumblr's team managed to do all these through a LAMP Stack before.

*One thing that I found out through pinging different Tumblr sites is that the blog sites are dispersed through multiple servers.*

Nonetheless, hacking the root of just one of those servers could compromise a ton of data. Furthermore, while some could argue that Tumblr may just be doing manual checks on each of its blogging sites, it still seems pretty risky and unpractical for Tumblr's team to do so because of the amount of data that Tumblr has. Because of this, I think there are still some aspects that checking manually hasn't covered yet, especially in terms of how Tumblr's team filters their user input before it enters their database.

**My main question: How does Tumblr (or any other similar site) filter its user input and thereby, prevent hacking and exploits from happening?**

Answer (score 1):

#### What is Tumblr.

Tumblr is a microbloggin service, which lets its users to post multimedia and short text blogs on their website.

#### Formating and styling blog

Every blog service lets its user to edit and share the content. At the same time they also let their users to style their blog depending on what type of service they are providing.

For instance, A company blog can never have a garden image as its background and at the same time a shopkeeper can never show a beach image; unless they are present at that place or include such objects in their work.

#### What Tumblr. does

Well, they just keep checking the files for any error!

As a general bloggin platform. It is necessary to allow the users to upload and style them blogs. And at the same time it is a job for the company to keep the control of how their service is used!

So Tumblr. keeps a great note on these things. They also donot allow to upload files that infect the system, and are well-known to delete such accounts if anything fishy is caught!

Tumblr. allows the users to upload files and multimedia that is used to style the blog. They used  a seperate platform where to save all such files! So when you upload it, it does not get executed on their system. They access it from the server or from the hard drive which these files are saved on and then provide you with the blog that includes those files.

#### What would I do

I would do the same, I would first upload and save the files on a seperate place, where if executed they donot harm my system if are infected by a virus. Not all the users upload virus. But once they do, you should use an antivirus system to detect and remove the virus and at the same time block that account.

I would have let the users to use my service, now its user's job to upload content and its my job to prevent hacking.

Comment: That is pretty interesting, and pinging different Tumblr sites seems to prove that this is indeed true. However, even hacking the root of just one server can compromise a lot of data. Furthermore, merely doing manual checks seems to be too risky, and I highly doubt that with the amount of data that Tumblr has, they would be able to check every single file. Because of this, I think there are still some aspects that your answer hasn't covered yet, especially in terms of how Tumblr's team filters its data.

Answer (score -3):

All this stuff (HTML/CSS/External scripts) does not run on Tumblr machines. So to them it does not matter. One is responsible for the stuff that runs on your own PC. As to Javascript it lives in a sandpit